# How to create a List of values if key is same for record in Spark Dataset

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have a Spark Dataset which has following schema.

Spark version 2.2 and java version 1.8.

df.printSchema()

```
                 root
                 |-- PROP: array (nullable = true)
                 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
                 |    |    |-- PVAL: string (nullable = true)
                 |    |    |-- _NAME: string (nullable = true)
```

df.show()

```
       [[200 Hours,displayName],[f44066,feature.id], [f48062,feature.id],[f30079,feature.id], [f30078,feature.id], [f30077,feature.id],[text1,description]]
       [[300 Hours,displayName],f44022,feature.id], [f48033,feature.id],[f30044,feature.id], [f30055,feature.id], [f30066,feature.id],[text2,description]]
```

Basically, wherever NAME is same,need list of values for that for each record level. In the above dataset, feature.id is same, so need list of values at record level.

## ExpectedDataset

```
       [200 Hours,displayName],[[f44066,f48062,f30079,f30078,f30077],feature.id],[text1,description]
       [300 Hours,displayName],[[f44022,f48033,f30044,f30055,f30066],feature.id],[text2,description]
```

Can someone help on this?.

Comment: your array size is fixed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

combination of `explode`, `collect_list` should give you your desired output

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("sno", monotonically_increasing_id())
   .select(col("sno"), explode(col("PROP")).as("PROP"))
   .select(col("sno"), col("PROP.*"))
   .groupBy("sno", "_NAME")
   .agg(collect_list("PVAL").as("PVAL"))
   .groupBy("sno")
   .agg(collect_list(struct("PVAL", "_NAME")).as("PROP"))
   .drop("sno")
```

.

Comment: Thanks Ramesh:). It was very helpful.

Comment: That also answered my question:). Will update that too.Thx

Comment: posted another questions,which regards to parsing nested XML. Can you please look into it. I am expecting above schema(array(struct(key,value), so that i can use Pivot function and transform into SparkDataset.